# Trying to find submit button in elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

im trying to code a steambot in python that will post in steamgroup;Im having problem with last step,
i cant find the sumbit button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium" id="commentthread_General_34191408_submit">
                                            <span>Post Discussion</span>
                                        </button>
```

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify the *submit* button with text as **Post Discussion** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn_green_white_innerfade.btn_medium[id^='commentthread_General_'][id$='_submit']>span")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium' and starts-with(@id, 'commentthread_General_')]/span[text()='Post Discussion']")
  ```

---

However, as it is a *submit* button so moving ahead you will invoke `click()` on it, so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn_green_white_innerfade.btn_medium[id^='commentthread_General_'][id$='_submit']>span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium' and starts-with(@id, 'commentthread_General_')]/span[text()='Post Discussion']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much,Worked

Answer (score 1):

Here is your button, works 100%. I checked it locally.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
```

Comment: What do you mean, you checked it locally? Pasting HTML into an XPath helper tool and testing against it is great, but there's no way to guarantee 100% that this works without seeing the whole page. There may be multiple `button` elements with `submit` type, or the button may be hidden in an `iframe` in which case this would not work at all.

Comment: Yes, u r right. I'm always checking that Xpath is working using helper tool. When I'm saying 100% I mean, that Xpath is correct. I agree that, I can't guarantee, that its gonna work if there is other elements on the page with same attributes or iframes, but since in questions we have only this HTML, it,s should work. Thank u.

Comment: Your XPath also won't compile because you have `'submit'` in single quotes, and your XPath is also enclosed in single quotes. It should be changed to `"//button[@type='submit']"`.